# PHP - using Array in a function and getting Undefined Index error

Tags: php, arrays, function, undefined

i'm using an old code, working on php4, but i get an undefined index notice, and function didnt work in php5

i have an array :

```
$tabStdDVD = array( 
485=>array ('nom'=>"Studio 1",'reduc'=>"0",'delais'=>"4",'rayon'=>"H 2",'valide'=>"1",'valide_dvd_promo'=>"0",'valide_dvd'=>"1"), 
319=>array ('nom'=>"un deuxieme tudio",'reduc'=>"0",'delais'=>"2",'rayon'=>"I2-6",'valide'=>"1",'valide_dvd_promo'=>"0",'valide_dvd'=>"1"),);
```

when i try to use it in the following function :

```
function studio($idStd,$typeS){
global $tabStdDVD;
 $res=$tabStdDVD[$idStd][$typeS] ;
return $res;
}
```

this function didn't work, and i get an notice : undefined index '' in my apache error log..

i think it's an global array issue or something like that..

thank you for your help

Comment: And how are you calling the function `studio` ? what are the values of those two parameters it has?

Comment: everytime you are start using `global`, you should start refactoring.

Comment: its working bro see https://eval.in/178441

Comment: yes, it's works on eval.in, but on my apache serveur, with my config (superglobal off, etc..) is doesn't..

Answer (score 0):

ok, i find why.

i need to call the function with my array in arguments..

```
studio($tabStdDVD,$idStd,$TypeS)
```

and in my function :

```
function studio($tabStdDVD,$idStd,$typeS) 
{..}
```